# Sails js,find user using either email or username

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to login user using either username or email i.e user can enter either email or password and should be able to log in. However, so far I am able to use one of them.

Here is the code tried so far.

```
authenticate: function (req, res) {
    var username =  req.body.username;
    var email = req.body.email;
    users.findOne({ 
            or: [
                {username: username},
                {email: email}
            ]
    }).exec(function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);
        if (err) {
            return res.json({err});
        } else if (!user) {
            var err = new Error('User not found.');
            err.status = 401;
            return res.json({err});
        } else {
            require('bcrypt').compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, result) {
                if(result === true) {
                    return res.json({user});
                } else {
                    return res.json({err});
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though sails waterline is not as powerful as direct access to any one db, it can do what you want here and much more. The [docs](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language) give some good examples of what's possible.

I don't know exactly how you are passing in the username or email to your request object, but something like this should work:

```
authenticate: function(req, res) {
    var username = req.param('username'); // or however you get this
    var email = req.param('email'); // or however you get this
    Users.findOne({
        or: [{username: username}, {email: email}]
    }).exec(function(err, user) {
        // handle the error, or make use of found user...
    });
}
```

You can also handle the case where user hands you an input that could be either a username or email...

```
var identifier = req.param('identifier'); // could be a username or an email
```

And then modify your `or` array to:

```
or: [{username: identifer}, {email: identifier}]
```

if you use the action 2 style, you can do
       ```

```
var identifier = inputs.identifier;
    var userRecord = await User.findOne({
      or : [{username: identifier}, {email: identifier}]
    });
```

Comment: i am passing parameter in request body.

Comment: see updated code, i've used you suggestion but getting error " Converting circular structure to JSON"

Comment: Try putting `user` or `error` in your `res.json` instead of `{user}` or `{error}`.

Comment: Can you use console.logs to see if you get expected results before you use `res` to wrap up? The user should definitely be "jsonable", but the error may have some circular references. Maybe `res.send(error)` would work.

Comment: sorry that was my mistake, i was providing only one parameter. It works, thanks for your help and time.